# Autocomplete disambiguous commands/files in Windows Command Prompt/PowerShell

Tags: windows, command-line, autocomplete

One of my high school networking courses has me using a program to simulate servers and networks, which allows me to use virtual shells on end devices (eg. PCs and, if remotely connected, switches/routers). The interesting thing on these shells is that they don't require the full command/argument to be typed out in order to process.

For example, the `systeminfo` command can be executed by typing either `systeminfo` or simply `sy`, as [no other commands start with `sy`, but there are others that start with `s`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZrtx.png) (hence the (dis)ambiguity in the commands).

Is there any way to emulate this shorthand functionality on the Command Prompt/PowerShell?

Comment: Make batch files?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I was thinking of doing that, but I haven't the slightest clue how I would do that.

Comment: Make a file called `sy.bat`, inside it put the `systeminfo` command, save it someplace in your Path (so you can call it from anyplace), then type `sy` and it should work. :)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I don't mean for just `systeminfo`, I mean for any file/program that's in my current directory. Say I have three files in my current directory: `aa.exe`, `bb.exe`, and `bc.exe`. If I type `a` and hit enter, `aa.exe` should run. If I do the same with `b`, nothing will happen because there's ambiguity between `bb.exe` and `bc.exe`, requiring me to type either `bb` or `bc` for those programs

Comment: There's TAB completion -- If the files are in the current folder, hit `a`, and then hit TAB. It should autocomplete "aa.exe" and if ab.exe exists hitting tab again will autocomplete to that, etc.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 That's what I want to avoid, using tab. What if I have a very long file name with those three, maybe `CatsAreVeryFluffyILoveThemVeryMuch.exe`, and don't want it to take a whole line in my shell?

Comment: Tab completion is the way to go.  If you need to type the same long command often, you can create an alias in Powershell and use that instead.  Example: `new-alias cats C:\whatever\CatsAreVeryFluffyILoveThemVeryMuch.exe`  For command prompt, you can create shortcuts or batch files with short names to execute longer commands.  For example, what I do is I have a folder called Aliases, which is added to my PATH environment variable, and in this folder I keep a ton of shortcuts with short names for everything that I use.  I even have a shortcut to open this Aliases folder (as).

Comment: @Matt I'm talking about a generic works-for-any-folder solution, not just a simple New-Alias. So it doesn't matter if I'm in "C:\Users\Admin\" or "J:\Files\Music\", if I type enough of a filename that it's clear which one I'm referencing, I shouldn't have to hit tab to finish the filename.

Comment: Yes, like in Cisco IOS `sh run` can be used instead of `show running-config`  This sort of command completion doesn't make sense for Windows or Linux machines, as it does in smaller, controlled environments like Cisco IOS.  The number of possibilities (shell command versions and files in %PATH%) could cause undesired effects, and the same command would do different things on different machines.  It would lead to lazy scripting and mistakes in shell commands.  When you execute a shell command, you should be sure of what you're doing, and by using tab-completion you get the best of both worlds.

Comment: @Matt There we go! It's embarrassing to admit I forgot the name of IOS. Hmm, at least I have a reason now. Thanks for the insight!